# Insert string value to datetime column

Tags: mysql, asp.net, datetime

I have two columns named exam_date (string nvarchar) and submitted_date(Date Time). The exam_date will always be "dd-MM-yyyy" format.Now I want to insert exam_date to submitted date. How is it possible? 
I have tried like below but shows "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
 string submitted_date="12-04-2016";
 cmd111.Parameters.AddWithValue("@submitted_date",Convert.ToDateTime(submitted_date));
```

Comment: Why is a date a nvarchar at all?

Comment: yes,that was a mistaken . But I could not change the datatype now. That's why asking for solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime submittedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("12-04-2016", "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```

But you should really change the column `exam_date` to a `datetime` and not a `nvarchar` type.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
DateTime submitted_date= DateTime.ParseExact(exam_date, "d", null);
```

"d" stands for the short date pattern and null specifies that the current culture should be used for parsing the string.